# Nest simulator: C compiler cannot create executable

Tags: python, numpy, gcc, neural-network, nest-simulator

I spent a while looking at the other posts for this error, but nothing was relevant to my specific issue with a Nest installation.  Nest installation requires ./configure to install, according to

https://nest.github.io/nest-simulator/xcode_workflow

Kept getting the following error when running ./configure:

> C compiler cannot create executable

And after re-installing new versions of python, numpy, scipy, matplotlib, gcc, and who knows what else, I keep getting this error. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So, after tinkering around for some time, I finally decided to install Anaconda and used the following command to install the Nest (Neural) Simulation tool:

> ./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/nest --without-openmp

This terminal command finally let me continue with the make, make install, and make installcheck portions of the Nest Neural Simulator tool installation.  Whew.